# Setup QGIS Display name to return only unique values from a search

Tags: qgis, sql, regular-expression

In QGIS I am trying to setup the Locator to return a matching Street Entry from the attribute table as opposed to all matching without creating a new merged layer. In the Display Expression, I tried using the collect function as follows:

```
 collect($geometry,"STREET_NM")
```

As well as a few variations of this, including `collect_geometries` and `line_merge`. If I do the search as just `STREET_NM` every line segment with that street name is returned; I only want 1 return and the geometry to be all the line segments matching that return. Is there an Expression that can perform this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QGIS versions older than 3.30 (but not older than 3.0), you can create an array of the ID of all features with the same streetname, order them by any criteria you want (here: attribute field `value`) and select only one element (feature) of this array - here, the first one, using [index operator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-index) `[0]`. You could also delete the `order_by` part to just select an arbitrary feature.

```
$id = array_agg ($id, filter:=street_name='Bond Street', order_by:=value)[0]
```

*Screenshot: the feature containing `street_name` = `Bond Street` with the smallest number in the `value` field is selected:*
[image]

Comment: I'm no longer working on this but it should come in handy for sure. Not sure which one to accept as the final answer though, I suppose the one that will work going forward?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_feature()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#get-feature) function to get only the first matching feature, than get the feature's id with [`feature_id ()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-record-and-attributes-feature-id) (this is [available since QGIS 3.30](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog330/index.html#feature-add-feature-id-function); see the other solution for older QGIS versions). Compare this with the variable `@id` (same as `$id` in earlier versions) that returns the ID of the current feature.

The whole expression looks like this. Replace `street_name` with the fieldname, `your_streetname` with the actual streetname you're looking for:

```
@id = feature_id (get_feature (@layer, 'street_name', 'your_streetname'))
```

*Only the first feature that matches the streetname is selected:*
[image]